# Ubuntu 10.04 still supported but 10.10 not

Tags: 10.10, 10.04, support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does Ubuntu mean by “support” for its releases?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/130092/what-does-ubuntu-mean-by-support-for-its-releases)

Can someone explain to me why an Ubuntu version that is released later and has a higher version number (10.10) loses support and no longer is updated whereas a previous version (10.04) has support until next year? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Because 10.04 is a long term support relise and 10.10 is a regular one. Read from Ubuntu wiki about it: [LTS](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LTS/)

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 10.04 is an LTS version. Every forth release Ubuntu sets a version as LTS, meaning "Long term support". They generally focus more on stability for these, and less on new features.

The reason they have this is so companies that rely on Ubuntu can know they will be supported for a long time without having to upgrade every six months.

Ubuntu makes it easy to upgrade directly from LTS to LTS for this reason.

The latest LTS is 12.04, this one.